# How can I use json data with & symbol using json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have tried with the following code:

```js
$.get("/a.php?op=ajax&section=b&cat_name=" + name.replaceAll("%", "")) + "&a=" + aname.replaceAll("%", "_"),function(resp) {

});
```

In my `name` value contains more than one `&` symbol. At that time I couldn't pass the full value because of when one `&` symbol occur then, it breaks my data.
For example my `name = 'DisplayPort & Mini DisplayPort Connector'`
I got only  'DisplayPort'.I didn't get the remaining part.

Answer (score 1):

Use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode special characters in query parameters. If you do this, you also don't need to remove `%`, it will encode them properly.

```
$.get("/a.php?op=ajax&section=b&cat_name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "&a=" + encodeURIComponent(aname),function(resp) {

});
```